# Why the int type takes up 8 bytes in BSS section but 4 bytes in DATA section

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am trying to learn the structure of executable files of C program. My environment is GCC and 64bit Intel processor.

Consider the following C code `a.cc`.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int x;

int main(){
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(x));
  return 10;
}
```

The `size -o a` shows

```
 text      data     bss     dec     hex filename
 1134       552       8    1694     69e a
```

After I added another initialized global variable y.

```
int y=10;
```

The `size a` shows (where `a` is the name of the executable file from a.cc)

```
 text      data     bss     dec     hex filename
 1134       556      12    1702     6a6 a
```

As we know, the `BSS` section stores the size of uninitialized global variables and `DATA` stores initialized ones.

1. **Why `int` takes up 8 bytes in BSS? The `sizeof(x)` in my code shows that the `int` actually takes up 4 bytes.**
2. **The `int y=10` added 4 bytes to DATA which makes sense since `int` should take 4 bytes. But, why does it adds 4 bytes to BSS?**

The difference between two `size` commands stays the same after deleting the two lines `#include ...`.

**Update:**
I think my understanding of BSS is wrong. It may not store the uninitialized global variables. As the Wikipedia says "The size that BSS will require at runtime is recorded in the object file, but BSS (unlike the data segment) doesn't take up any actual space in the object file." For example, even the one line C code `int main(){}` has `bss 8`.

**Does the 8 or 16 of BSS comes from `alignment`?**

Comment: have you looked at the assembly code? it could be declaring in bss and using later

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I saw that in Wikipedia, which makes me confused  about the BSS section. Thanks.

Comment: When there are no global variables, `bss` is 0?

Comment: Are you talking about C or C++? You mention C throughout but your sample program is C++. What BSS size do you get if you remove the variable `x`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits No. It is still 8. Even I just have int main(){}. The bss is 0.

Comment: @Gilles Even I removed the includes, the difference stays the same. The difference also stays no matter GCC or G++.

Comment: This code is not valid C, and `size -o` can't possibly print 8 because `-o` means "octal". Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: @Alper Thanks. I mean the executable files. I made a typo when I write "object files" in the first line of my question.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks. It is `size a`. I made a mistake when typing.

Comment: @DTSCode I saw "  
.globl  x
  .bss
  .align 4
  .type x, object
  .size x, 4
"

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't, it takes up 4 bytes regardless of which segment it's in.  You can use the `nm` tool (from the GNU binutils package) with the `-S` argument to get the names and sizes of all of the symbols in the object file.  You're likely seeing secondary affects of the compiler including or not including certain other symbols for whatever reasons.

For example:

```
$ cat a1.c
int x;
$ cat a2.c
int x = 1;
$ gcc -c a1.c a2.c
$ nm -S a1.o a2.o

a1.o:
0000000000000004 0000000000000004 C x

a2.o:
0000000000000000 0000000000000004 D x
```

One object file has a 4-byte object named `x` in the uninitialized data segment (`C`), while the other object file has a 4-byte object named `x` in the initialized data segment (`D`).

Comment: +1 the linked startup code in the runtime library may well be accounting for the additional space being seen with `size` (and if I had to *guess* (always dangerous), i'd say it was something like `errno` or any of a handful of other commodities; mach-o images include a stub binder for the dynalib loader, for example).

Comment: Thanks. I would like to know more about the structure of the executable file. Such as, what the BSS really does?

Comment: @PengZhang: the BSS segment is usually a segment that has an address and a size (so it can be mapped to memory) but contains no actual initialized data (so there is nothing to store into a file). After loading, it is available as readable and writable memory; just like common DATA.

Comment: @Jongware Thanks. So while the DATA and TEXT will being copied into memory, the BSS will not? Does BSS serves as a notification to OS so that linux know how to allocate memories needed by the program (besides TEXT and DATA) when loading the program?

Comment: @PengZhang: that sounds about right. Find a good description of the executable format for your platform, and find a tool (or write one!) to dump the raw data. You will see that there is no file data associated with a BSS segment.