# uninitialized variables of a object file not showing in linux size command

Tags: c, linux, data-segment

Created a source file test1.c with the following code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int x = 15;
int d = 15;
int m = 18;
int k = 0;
int c = 0;
int l;

int main()
{
    int y = 5;
    int ma = 10;
    int am = 10;
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled the following code with the command :

```
gcc -c test1.c
```

To check the size of the various segments of memory used the size command :

```
size test1.o
```

The output that I obtained :

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex  filename
   114       12       8     134      86   test1.o
```

And I found that whenever I add a global uninitialized variable like *int l* in above the bss segment stays unchanged. The bss segment shows just those variables that are initialized to 0. But according to definition bss segment should contain uninitialized variables.

Also whenever I add a initialized global pointer like :

```
int *p = &x
```

it increases the size of the data segment by 12 rather than 8 ( which is the size of a integer pointer on my machine ).

What is wrong with my interpretation ?

Comment: I know it includes uninitialized static variables

Comment: I will bet the size of the BSS section increases if you compile with the `-fno-common` flag for gcc .  What's special about your `l` variable is that it is a [tentative definitiion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095861/about-tentative-definition) , so posssibly there's no space allocated for that variable in the binary file  until you run the linker.

Answer (score 0):

> *And I found that whenever I add a global uninitialized variable like int l in above the bss segment stays unchanged.*

That's the expected behaviour. Quoting from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) article, (*emphasis mime*)

> [...] Since the BSS segment only holds variables that don't have any value yet, it doesn't actually need to store the image of these variables. **The size that BSS will require at runtime is recorded in the object file, but BSS (unlike the data segment) doesn't take up any actual space in the object file.**

So, it's unlikely that the size for `bss` will change, upon changing the number of uninitialized variables with static storage. You can refer to [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24833649/2173917) for more elaboration on the *why* part.

Comment: In the above code I have three global variables : k , c and l . Why does bss show size of k and c but not l ?