# Why .bss size decrease when adding an initialized static variable?

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management

I understand that the default alignment of `.bss` is 8 bytes for GCC as mentioned in this question [Why the int type takes up 8 bytes in BSS section but 4 bytes in DATA section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833400/why-the-int-type-takes-up-8-bytes-in-bss-section-but-4-bytes-in-data-section)

So with this program:

```
int main(){
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have something like this:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1418     544       8    1970     7b2 test
```

When I add an static variable with initialization to increase `.data` (and it does):

```
static int var = 255;

int main(){
    
    return 0;
}
```

I see that the size of `.bss` also decrease 4 bytes:

```
  text     data     bss     dec     hex filename
  1418      548       4    1970     7b2 test
```

Please tell me why ?

Comment: .bss should't take any memory. I guess this behavior maybe due to alignment. It is dependent on compiler implementation.

Comment: Have you tried looking at output from `readelf`, `nm`, etc. to see if you can determine what symbols are at the address[es] in bss?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE yes, I did, I am looking at the default linker file of gcc also, since I am using the default linker file. I think it's from the way of alignment between `.bss` and `.data`, but still not find out the logic.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. For which architecture with which compiler version and flags did you compile?

Answer (score 1):

The `.bss` has the *size* of the uninitialized global variables. These will be initialized to zero upon loading of the program.

If you initialize a global variable to something other than zero, it will no longer be in the `.bss` but will be in the `.data` segment. The data segment contains all initialized global variables (with their initial value).

Hence, the size of the `.bss` decreases and the size if the `.data` increases.

Comment: The variable doesn't exist in the first version. So there is no uninitialized variable moved.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of initialization of bss by reserving the basic 8 bytes, introducing all zeros so the memory manager does not read rubbish, but when we finally créate a variable that fits in 4 bytes, the bss is reduced (to occupy the less possible memory).